# PyCharm: Can't create remote python interpreter using docker-compose

Tags: macos, docker-compose, pycharm, macos-catalina

On attempt to create docker-compose python interpreter in PyCharm I get error:

> Error while parsing "/Users/belek/Projects/project/docker-composee.yml": Process `docker-compose config` failed.

Itself docker-compose works fine. The `docker-compose config` command running in terminal works too.

Before updating macOS and PyCharm I was using docker-compose python interpreter succesfully. Can't understand what's wrong. I created issue in JB YouTrack, but no response.

PyCharm 2019.2.3
macOS Catalina 10.15

Comment: I am facing the same issue

Comment: @OmairShamshir if find solution, please provide answer

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The following helped me.

Go to 'System Preferences' -> 'Security & Privacy'.

Add PyCharm to "Full Disk Access" and to "Developer tools".

[image]

[image]

Comment: Found on JetBrains Bug & Issue Tracker:
*If you don't see Developer Tools, you will need to install Xcode*

Comment: In my case, adding PyCharm to "Full Disk Access" is enough, restart PyCharm then issue's gone