# PyCharm: Error while parsing docker-compose.yml docker-compose config failed

Tags: pycharm

When trying to configure docker-compose interpreter in PyCharm on macOS Catalina, I'm getting the following error:

> Error while parsing
>   "/Users//PycharmProjects/project/docker-composee.yml": Process
>   docker-compose config failed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyCharm: Can't create remote python interpreter using docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58371028/pycharm-cant-create-remote-python-interpreter-using-docker-compose)

Answer (score 33):

1) On your macOS go to `System Preferences | Security & Privacy`

2) Make sure PyCharm is in "Full Disk Access" and "Developer tools".

EDIT: you may need to install Xcode for "Developer tools" to appear.

Also, vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-38501

Comment: Seems to have worked.  It is worth noting after installing Xcode you may have to wait a little for the "Developer tools" to appear in Privacy.  For the Pycharm devs, it seems a bit ridiculous a 7.5GB download is needed for this fix.

Comment: PyCharm did not show as a preselected option for me under Developer tools. I used the + icon and added PyCharm from the application folder. After restarting PyCharm the error went away

Comment: I had this issue with PHPStorm and this solved it for me!

Answer (score 1):

For me (Linux, docker-compose v2, docker-compose.yml version: 3.9), with docker-compose v2.2.3 the issue was that the wrong docker-compose executible was mapped to the correct

Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Docker -> tools

Change:
`/usr/bin/docker-compose` to `/home/{INSERT_YOUR_USER_HERE_AS_TILDA_DOES_NOT_WORK}/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose` (or wherever the correct version of docker compose is).
Once you will enter a version which is docker-compose v2 compatible you would also have tick the checkbox.

[image: click checkbox]